# Windows Mobile 6.5 Development with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-mobile

I have some handheld computers that are running Windows Mobile 6.5. I tried to open an old application that was created using Visual Studio 2012 but it wouldn't let me edit anything. I have looked all over and it appears I have to get an old version of Visual Studio to make changes to the app for Windows Mobile 6.5?

Comment: "I have some handheld computers that are running Windows Mobile 6.5. I tried to open an old application that was created using Visual Studio 2012" - this can not be true as VS2012 does NOT support Windows Mobile 6.x development!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Visual Studio 2008 is the latest version with support for Windows Mobile 6.5.x
You have to install it and the Windows Mobile 6.5 SDK from Microsoft as well.

Comment: So even though I own VS 2012 I have to buy VS 2008 or is there another way?

Comment: Correct. You need to purchase the (non-free) [Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7940).